# Finding an index in an array in python

Tags: python, indexing

I have looked at 
[Finding the index of an item given a list containing it in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-given-a-list-containing-it-in-python?lq=1)

and I have not found a solution. I have a list I appended of 426 values and I am looking for the index of 'KORD' but it claims it is not in the list, when it is.

```
metar_txt = open("metar.txt", "r") 
lines = metar_txt.readlines() 
for line in lines: 
    if len(line) > 20: 
        stations = []
        stations.append(line.split(' ')[0])
        print stations.index('KORD')
metar_txt.close()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-9271d129d452> in <module>()
      5         stations = []
      6         stations.append(line.split(' ')[0])
----> 7         print stations.index('KORD')
      8 metar_txt.close()

ValueError: 'KORD' is not in list
```

Comment: Have you printed out your array to make sure that there isn't anything appended or pre-fixed to KORD that will mess up your matching? Also put stations = [] outside of the loop

Comment: Check stations.index('KORD\n') or can you show us how a line from lines  look like?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create the list outside the loop, you are only storing a single element in your list as `stations = []` in the loop keeps creating an empty list and then you add a single element, repeating each iteration:

```
stations = []
for line in lines: 
    if len(line) > 20:
```

If you are calling index in the loop each time then unless you add the substring on the very first iteration then you are going to keep getting an index error, not sure what your goal is but I imagine indexing when the loop completes will work:

```
with open("metar.txt", "r")  as metar_txt:
    stations = []
    for line in metar_txt: 
        if len(line) > 20: 
            stations.append(line.rstrip().split(' ')[0]
    print stations.index('KORD') # outside loop
```

If you just want the index of where it would appear keep a count as you go only incrementing the count when `if len(line) > 20` is True which would be exactly the same as trying to find the substring index in the list at the end of your loop:

```
with open("metar.txt", "r")  as metar_txt:
    stations = []
    i = 0
    for line in metar_txt:
        if len(line) > 20:
            w = line.rstrip().split(' ')[0]
            if w == "KORD":
                print(i)
            i += 1
```

Lastly if you are trying to keep some index record for multiple words you can use a dict so finding the index will be 0(1):

```
with open("metar.txt", "r")  as metar_txt:
    stations = {}
    i = 0
    for line in metar_txt:
        if len(line) > 20:
            w = line.rstrip().split(' ')[0]
            stations[w] = i
            i += 1
print(stations["KORD"])
```

If you want efficient lookups and to keep the order you can use an `OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
with open("metar.txt", "r")  as metar_txt:
    stations = OrderedDict()
    i = 0
    for line in metar_txt:
        if len(line) > 20:
            w = line.rstrip().split(' ')[0]
            stations[w] = i
            i += 1
```

So `for st in stations:print(st)` will output the stations in the order added and `stations["word"]` will give you the index.

Or using a genexp and str.partition as Jon commented:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
with open("metar.txt", "r")  as metar_txt:
 lines = (line.partition(' ')[0] for line in metar_txt if len(line) > 20)
 stations = OrderedDict((el, idx) for idx, el in enumerate(lines))
```

Or using `itertools.count` with a single genexp:

```
with open("metar.txt", "r")  as metar_txt:
    from itertools import count
    cn = count()
    stations = OrderedDict((line.rstrip().split(' ')[0], next(cn))
                           for line in metar_txt if len(line) > 20)
```

Comment: what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: the stations array is long, but contains 4 letter entries. I'm look for the index of the entry 'KORD' which is in the list.

Comment: Now I realize my print statement was not lined up. thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing there's also an issue of using `str.split` with an explicit delimiter - so it has the potential to still end up with an `\n` at the end.

Comment: @JonClements, the OP is only taking the first subelement so unless there is only one word which seems unlikely with the len() test that should not be an issue

Comment: @PadraicCunningham indeed... could well end up being a gotcha later though :) (you know I'm pedantic by now Padraic!)

Comment: @JonClements, added rstrip just for you ;) Don't see much of you these days, you must be flat out moderating!

Comment: @Padraic how's about: `lines = (line.partition(' ')[0] for line in metar_txt if line.rstrip()); stations = OrderedDict((el, idx) for idx, el in enumerate(lines))` ? (or similar with line length etc...)

Comment: @JonClements, yep, added cheers, added a version using `itertools.count` too for a single genexp